# Gradle - Conditionally add configuration

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project with configuration below

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        credentials {
            username "$System.env.REPOSITORY_USER"
            password "$System.env.REPOSITORY_PWD"
        }
        url "$System.env.REPOSITORY_HOME" + /nexus/content/groups/public/"
    }
}
```

Ideally only the build server should know the repository username and password that has publish rights, everyone else should have read only access (the credentials block should not be applied). Is there a way I could conditionally add the `credentials` block based on if both `REPOSITORY_USER` and `REPOSITORY_PWD` is populated?

I'm open to better solutions if you have any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to use something like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

if (System.env.REPOSITORY_USER != null && System.env.REPOSITORY_PWD != null) {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // Setup here what you need
            credentials {
            }
        }
    }
}
```